# Trying to change object value and reference value but not coordinates

Tags: lua, coronasdk, luabind, corona-storyboard

I have this function

```
local function cambiodesp(old,new)
   block[new]= block[old]
end
```

and i have this:

```
random=4 
local image = display.newImage(images[random], 0, 0)
image.value = random
image.x = 161
image.y = 451
block[0] = image

random=1
image.value = random 
local image = display.newImage(images[random], 0, 0)
image.x = 161
image.y = 515
block[1] = image
```

i want to change the block.value of the images, the reference of the images in block, but i dont want to change the coordinates.
I'm calling the function:

```
cambiodes(0,1)
```

but the coordinates are changing and i don`t know what to do.

I hope you can give me an answer, advice or whatever you think.

Thank you very much

Comment: why is the image.y different on the other?

Comment: Because i`m making a transition. from image in block[0] to image in block[1].

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the entire table (reference); if you want to keep x and y coordinates, just save them and re-assign (assuming everything else happens as you want it):

```
local function cambiodesp(old,new)
   local x, y = block[new].x, block[new].y
   block[new]= block[old]
   block[new].x, block[new].y = x,y
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not working. Because the coordinates of block[old] are changing. before the function were 451 and after the function were 515. And i try to to this:           local x, y = block[new].x, block[new].y
                local x2, y2 = block[old].x, block[old].y
                block[new]= block[old]
                block[new].x, block[new].y = x,y
                block[old].x, block[old].y = x2,y2   (it doesn`t work, please please help me). Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
local function swap(old,new)
    block[old], block[new] = block[new], block[old] #swap references
    block[old].x, block[old].y, block[new].x, block[new].y = block[new].x, block[new].y, block[old].x, block[old].y #re-set coordinates
end
```